# boost operator totally_ordered composed of less_than_comparable and equality_comparable

Tags: c++, boost

As [boost operator document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/utility/operators.htm#grpd_oprs) say,template totally_ordered is composed of template less_than_comparable and tempalte equality_comparable.

It means that if a class inherents from template totally_ordered, operator== must be implemented when using operator== or operator!=.

In my view, if operator< is implemented, operator== can be generated automatically like (!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)).So, is operator== necessary ?

code piece:

```
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
class Foo : public boost::totally_ordered<Foo>
{
        public:
                explicit Foo(const int num) : m_nMem(num){}
                friend bool operator< (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
                {
                        return lhs.m_nMem < rhs.m_nMem;
                }
                // Is operator== necessary ?
                // Is operator== equal to (!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs)) ?
                //friend bool operator== (const Foo& lhs, const Foo& rhs)
                //{
                //      return lhs.m_nMem == rhs.m_nMem;
                //}
        private:
                int m_nMem;

};

int main()
{
        Foo foo_1(1), foo_2(2);
        foo_1 == foo_2; // compiler error , no operator==
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A strict weak ordering may rate unequal elements equivalent¹
E.g.:

```
struct Point { 
     int x,y; 
     bool operator<(Point const& other) const { return x < other.x; }
};
```

Here, Points would be ordered by `x`, and points having equal `x` would be *equivalent* according to your suggested implementation.

However, since `y` may be different, clearly the points are not guaranteed to be *equal*.

Only if the comparison is in fact a total ordering, then we can generate the equality operation using the relative comparison operators. I can only suspect the library authors

- wanted the users to be very conscious of this implications
- realized that using `(!(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs))` might lead to suboptimal performance

¹ https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html